# google maps updating div with info window event on map and sidebar

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the following code to display my map plus 2 seperate div. One has a list of features (sidebar) and one has the result of the infowindow click event. 
I can get the expected behavior when I click on the map, but the sidebar features, while correctly label on the map, do not update the "BottomInfoWindow" DIV. I cannot seem to get the right place to make that happen. On a less related note, I also would like to show the fusion table card in the "BottomInfoWindow" DIV, but haven't figured out how to incorporate that into a google map. If you know of an example that would be great too.

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body, #map_canvas {
    width:   900px;
    height:  550px;
    margin:  0;
    padding: 0;
}
    .infowindow * {font-size: 90%; margin: 0}
.auto-style1 {
    font-size: small;
}
</style>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 

<!-- Initialize --> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart', 'table', 'geomap']});

var tableId ='1aa5D73bkLrD6aY7W7MaU5C4z-v6HRM6aWnhg19N5';

function  createSidebar() {
 //set the query using the parameter
  var queryText = encodeURIComponent("http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=SELECT * FROM "+tableId);
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(queryText);
  var queryText = encodeURIComponent("SELECT 'Sample Location', 'X', 'Y' FROM "+tableId);
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq='  + queryText);

  //set the callback function
  query.send(getData);

}

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(createSidebar);</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var FTresponse = null;
//define callback function, this is called when the results are returned
function getData(response) {
if (!response) {
  alert('no response');
  return;
}
if (response.isError()) {
  alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
  return;
} 
  FTresponse = response;
  //for more information on the response object, see the documentation
  //http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#QueryResponse
  numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
  numCols = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();

  //concatenate the results into a string, you can build a table here
  fusiontabledata = "<table><tr>";
//  for(i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
    fusiontabledata += "<th>" + response.getDataTable().getColumnLabel(0) + "</th>";
//   }
  fusiontabledata += "</tr><tr>";

  for(i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
//    for(j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
      fusiontabledata += "<td><a href='javascript:myFTclick("+i+")'>"+response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0) + "</a></td>";
//    }
    fusiontabledata += "</tr><tr>";
  }
  fusiontabledata += "</table>"  
  //display the results on the page
  document.getElementById('sidebar').innerHTML = fusiontabledata;
  document.getElementById('BottomInfoWindow').innerHTML = event.infoWindowHtml;
}

function myFTclick(row) {
   //var description = FTresponse.getDataTable().getValue(row,0);
   var name = FTresponse.getDataTable().getValue(row,0);
   var lat =  FTresponse.getDataTable().getValue(row,2);
   var lng =  FTresponse.getDataTable().getValue(row,1);
   var position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
   openInfoWindow(name, position);
}

function openInfoWindow(name, position) {
   // Set up and create the infowindow
   if (!infoWindow) infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
   infoWindow.setOptions({
      content: '<div class="FT_infowindow"><h3>' + name + 
               '</h3></div>',
      pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 2),
      position: position
    });
    // Infowindow-opening event handler
    infoWindow.open(map);
}   

var map = null;
var infoWindow = null;

function initialize() {
//SET CENTER  
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.68635054275792, -117.21382726097107),
      zoom: 16,
      scrollwheel:false,
      mapTypeControl: true,
      streetViewControl: false,
      overviewMapControl: true,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
      },
// CONTROLS      
      zoomControl: true,
      zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
      },
      mapTypeId: 'hybrid'
    });


  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({suppressInfoWindows: true,
      query: { from: tableId, select: 'Y, X'}});
  layer.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(layer, "click", function(event) {
    infoWindow.close();
    // alert("click:"+event.latLng+","+event.infoWindowHtml);
    openInfoWindow(event.row["Sample Location"].value, event.latLng);
    // infoWindow.setContent(event.infoWindowHtml);
    // infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    // infoWindow.open(map);
    document.getElementById('BottomInfoWindow').innerHTML = event.infoWindowHtml;
  });

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


//  createSidebar();
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<table style="width:100%;"><tr><td>
        <div id="map_canvas">
        </div>
</td><td>
<div id="sidebar" style="width:120px;height:550px; overflow:auto" class="auto-style1">
    </div>
</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">
        <div id="BottomInfoWindow" class="auto-style1">
        Result
        </div>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a javascript error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'infoWindowHtml' of undefined` in the [posted code](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zzn94kzx/) on this line:

```
document.getElementById('BottomInfoWindow').innerHTML = event.infoWindowHtml;
```

There is no `event` inside the `getData` function

If you want to use the code that exists, add that to `openInfoWindow()`

```
function openInfoWindow(name, position) {
    // Set up and create the infowindow
    if (!infoWindow) infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
    infoWindow.setOptions({
        content: '<div class="FT_infowindow"><h3>' + name +
            '</h3></div>',
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 2),
        position: position
    });
    // Infowindow-opening event handler
    infoWindow.open(map);
    document.getElementById('BottomInfoWindow').innerHTML = infoWindow.getContent();
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zzn94kzx/5/)

Note that the infoWindowHtml defined by the fusionTable (what your click listener is displaying in the "BottomInfoWindow" DIV) is not accessible from the sidebar, but you can recreate it in the openInfoWindow function.

To make them both the same (formated by the openInfoWindow function) change the `fusionTablesLayer` "click" handler as well:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, "click", function (event) {
    infoWindow.close();
    // alert("click:"+event.latLng+","+event.infoWindowHtml);
    openInfoWindow(event.row["Sample Location"].value, event.latLng);
    // infoWindow.setContent(event.infoWindowHtml);
    // infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    // infoWindow.open(map);
    document.getElementById('BottomInfoWindow').innerHTML = infoWindow.getContent();
});
```

Comment: I guess the last part, " you can recreate it in the openInfoWindow function" is where I am stuck. I was hoping that i could use the same formatting for both info windows.
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aaronwisher/zzn94kzx/4/)
I like how I can show a different label on the map that what is shown in the bottom div.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say.  My code has a single function to display the infowindow, whether it is from a map click or a sidebar click.  It doesn't display the infoWindowHtml property of the click event (that contains the infowindow that would open on the fusionTablesLayer by default).

Comment: No, your code works perfectly. I'm trying to get it to return identical bottom div result that clicking on the map returns. Currently, they have different results. when you click on the sidebar the map label and the bottom div are the same, whereas when you click on the map, the map label is different that the bottom div information. That is what I am after. Like you pointed out, the code is different for the sidebar click, then it is for the map click, and I need to add separate code in the sidebar click section to add separate formatting for the bottom div.

Comment: Do you want the bottom div to be the same as the infoWindow on the map?

Comment: Just the opposite. I want the map label to be the same in both click events, but the div to be formatted differently

Comment: They are now formatted the same.  You can't access the .infoWindowHtml property of the event from the sidebar.  Change the openInfoWindow function to format the div the way you want it.